# Why did Rav Shach zt"l say that it's apikorsus to study history?

Tags: chinuch-education, college-university-school, secular-culture, rav-joseph-ber-soloveitchik, rav-shach

I read on Wikipedia, citing the Michtavim v'Mamarim [of Rav Shach zt"l) volumes 1 pg. 109, pg.128,3 pg.31&39,4 pg.35,107, saying the following:

> He wrote that any secular studies were banned by the sages of the Talmud, and that specially the study of psychology and history is pure heresy.

If it is true that he wrote this, why? How could there be such an enormous and outstanding *machlokes* between Rav Shach zt"l and Rav Soloveitchik zt"l? Yes, granted they had very different hashkafos, but for Rav Shach to say that secular studies is apikorsus and Rav Soloveitchik that it is advisable for some to even get a PhD?

I think my bigger question though, is how people could so easily ignore the *shita* of a gaon like HaRav Shach. I am young and myself do a lot of secular studies, but feel a need to really understand the shitah. Why don't people give it more attention? It seems like it's for their own agenda and expediency that they don't discuss the Tzadik's ideas.

I know they aren't really ignoring as much as they disagree, but to not at least give it more thought? I bet the concept of removing or significantly diminishing secular studies in schools has not been seriously considered in quite a while. Even in the most lomdish yeshivos in America they do significant secular studies.

Comment: Perhaps R Shach was exaggerating? It's really hard to imagine which Ikar is being violated by studying history...

Comment: @DoubleAA - Rav Shach, with all due respect of course, sometimes "labels" things very black and white. So it's not surprising he would say something is complete apikorsus.

Comment: Something interesting: Rav Soloveitchik zt''l was a good friend of the Lubavitcher Rebbe, and Rav Shach zt''l considered the Lubavitcher Rebbe an apikorus.

Comment: **I think my bigger question though, is how people could so easily ignore the shita of a gaon like HaRav Shach.** We ignore plenty of other Gaonim.

Comment: Machlokot that range from Mitzva to Heresy are actually pretty common when discussing what materials are worth studying. Consider the Zohar, R Saul Liberman, R Yonason Eibshitz (or any other work which some rabbis accepted and some didn't, of which there are doubtless hundreds more).

Comment: **How could there be such an enormous and outstanding machlokes between Rav Shach zt"l and Rav Soloveitchik zt"l?** Are there not tons of arguments between sages in which they are bipolar opposites in opinion?

Comment: How about r. Shakhs being in opposition to most classic rabbinic greats; not just r. Soloveitchik.

Comment: check out shaarei Talmud Torah about Torah study and the proper way to study and live, by rabbi Leo Levi. It has approbations by rabbi moshe Feinstein, rabbi ovadya yosef, and rabbi yaakov kamanetzky. Needless to say, rabbi shakh claimed it was heretical, and railed against it. That's probably why you dont hear about r. Shakh's views about this sort of thing; most people are happy to be in the camp of the entire corpus of rabbinic literature cited in the book, and in the company of r. Feinstein et al.

Comment: The Mechaber in OC 307:16 says books of wars and battles are *moshav leitzim*, but this statement by Rav Shach sounds more general and intense (apikorsus being much worse)

Comment: @ezra It may not be surprising, but it still might be an exaggeration. I don't see what one has to do with the other.

Comment: It may also be related to how Rav Shach defines study of 'history'. He surely wouldn't object to Sefer Yosiphun which is clearly history and is accepted by Rishonim and Acharonim.

Answer (score 3):

This opinion of Rav Shach is undoubtedly stemming from the [Bartenura in Sanhedrin in the beginning of Chelek](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sanhedrin.10.1?with=Bartenura&lang=bi). He say included in sefarim chitzonim are  history books of nations who are idol worshipers.

> בספרים החיצונים. ספרי מינים, כגון ספרי אריסט״ו היוני וחביריו. ובכלל זה הקורא בספר דברי הימים של מלכי נכרים ובשירים של עגבים ודברי חשק שאין בהם חכמה ולא תועלת אלא איבוד זמן בלבד:

To answer your bigger question, probably most people ignore Rav Shach's opinion as most halachik sefarim have ignored this opinion of Bartenura. It is an old idea that was never accepted.